# How to remove unwanted elements in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In the method below, I'm trying to remove values in array input that are less than 0 and greater than 9. I've been doing research and I found that using `Arraylist.remove()` would probably be the best way but I am not familiar with that yet. So what I did is try to copy the whole array into a "garbage" array and only put values that are less than 0 and greater than 9. But my output still comes out to be `123145123145-110`?

```
 public static void test (){
 int[] input = {1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3,1,4,5,-1,10};

    int[] garbage = new int[input.length];
    for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if (input[i] < 0 && input[i] > 9){
            garbage[i] = input[i];
        }
        int x = input[i];
        System.out.print(x);
  }
```

//EDIT

```
  public static void votes(){
     int[] input = {1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3,1,4,5,-1,10,20};
        int count = 0;
        int[] garbage = new int[input.length];
        for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
            if (input[i]<0){
                garbage[count] = input[i];
                i++;
                count++;
            }
        int x = input[i];
        System.out.print(x);

        }

  }
```

Comment: I managed to remove anything less than 0 by doing this:       public static void votes(){
         int[] input = {1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3,1,4,5,-1,10,20};
   int count = 0;
   int[] garbage = new int[input.length];
   for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if (input[i]<0){
     garbage[count] = input[i];
     i++;
     count++;
    }
   int x = input[i];
   System.out.print(x);
   
   }
    
      }
but whenever I set the if condition to (input[i] < 0 && input[i] > 9), I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException errror

Comment: You're just copying stuff from `input` to `garbage` - why do you expect `input` to change ? also, please don't post code in comments - it's not readable - please edit/update your questions with any additional information

Comment: Do you really think an integer can be both less than 0 and greater than 9 at the same time?

Comment: Are you trying to print out each good value, change your original array, or both?

Comment: why don't you use an iterator? `iterator.remove()`

Comment: in addition to what the previous commentators have written, you also have set `int[] garbage` to have the same size as `int[] input`. additionally, numbers are being placed to the same index in `garbage` as the one they occupied in `input`. Both of these things are happening even though `garbage` should, logically, be shorter than `input`. basically, your `garbage` array will have a lot of zeroes in it because it has just as many indexes as `input` but only a small portion of them are being filled, and the compiler will make the unfilled indexes zeroes

Comment: @user2532739 I am trying to print out values that are greater than 0 and less than 9.

Comment: also, as Nishant Shreshth has pointed out, you need to change the `&&` (which means 'and') to `||` (which means 'or')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong interval.

```
if (input[i] < 0 && input[i] > 9)
```

should be this

```
if (input[i] < 0 || input[i] > 9)
```

Your garbage should be empty, but your syso.println just shows all elements in the input array anyway. Another problem is that you will have the elements 0 <= input[i] <= 9 in your garbage array and a lot of zeros between them, if you use the same index for both arrays. All in all your code should look like this

```
int[] garbage = new int[input.length];
int j = 0;
for (int i=0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] >= 0 && input[i] <= 9){
        garbage[j] = input[i];
        j++;
        System.out.print(garbage[j]);
    }
```

}

This way you will see the element added to garbage. And all zeros are at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your output prints out the value in the array regardless of its value as it is outside your if statement, try moving the closing `}` for your if statement after the print statement, like so

```
for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] < 0 && input[i] > 9){
        garbage[i] = input[i];
    //}  <--- move this to
        int x = input[i];
        System.out.print(x);
    } // <--- here
}
```

However the values inside your `garbage` array are now those which you don't want (less than 0 and greater 10), if you printed out those you would find the expected output.

If you want an array with the values you want then make an array and add that way

```
int[] keeping = new int[input.length];
int j = 0;
for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] > 0 && input[i] <= 9){
        keeping[j] = input[i];
        j++;
        int x = input[i];
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go backward so when u remove something u wont be visiting the index

for (int i = sizeOfArray - 1, i >= 0; i--) {
  if array[i] > 0 remove object;
}

sorry for the sudo code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since in the comments you said that what you really want to do is print out the elements >0 and <9, not actually change the array, this become pretty simple.

```
public static void votes(){
    int[] input = {1,2,3,1,4,5,1,2,3,1,4,5,-1,10,20};
    for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if (input[i] >= 0 && input[i] <= 9){
            System.out.print(input[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And thats it!